# Variable passed from one function to another become undefined after .post with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parameters

I have a function successfully pass `data_user_id` with a value of `2` into the `function getOptionsList(fieldname_validation,data_user_id)` But then, I think somehow the .post statment's async nature took the value out so when I do a .post in the `getOptionsList` function, then the data_user_id will be undefined in function it passed next. Like this:

```
function getOptionsList(fieldname_validation,data_user_id){ 
        $.post('Controller.php',
        {
            action: 'get_options_list',
            user: userJson
        },
        function(data, textStatus, fieldname_validation,data_user_id) {
            data_user_id=data_user_id;
            showOptionsList(data, fieldname_validation,data_user_id);
            $('#indicator').hide();
        }, 
        "json"      
    );  
}

function showOptionsList(jsonData, fieldname_validation,data_user_id){

    alert('showOptionsList ran!');
    alert(data_user_id);//Here the same variable will alert as undefined.
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How is jQuery's $.post method returning the data_user_id as the fourth argument ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `data_user_id` as a parameter to your inner function, so it's distinct from the parameter of the outer method. Since the [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method will only provide 3 parameters to the callback, the fourth parameter will always be `undefined` (the third parameter will be a `jqXhr` object, which I don't believe is what you expect).

The solution is to remove this parameter (and probably `fieldname_validation` as well):

```
function getOptionsList(fieldname_validation,data_user_id){ 
        $.post('Controller.php',
        {
            action: 'get_options_list',
            user: userJson
        },
        function(data, textStatus) {
            showOptionsList(data, fieldname_validation, data_user_id);
            $('#indicator').hide();
        }, 
        "json"      
    );  
}
```

Comment: You should probably remove `data_user_id=data_user_id;` as well. Not that it makes a difference, but it's useless.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah yes, I didn't see that. Thanks.